# R lattice bar chart out of position

Tags: r, rstudio, lattice

I'm plotting the following data as a barchart

```
01/31/1996      -7.3667
02/29/1996       0.9413
03/31/1996       9.3252
04/30/1996       0.3147
05/31/1996       8.8593
06/30/1996      10.0297
07/31/1996       0.64i3
08/31/1996       2.1397
09/30/1996       0.6759
10/31/1996      -1.5579
11/30/1996       2.9493
....             ....
goes to 2012..
```

like

```
barchart(V2~V1, data=differences)
```

where v2 is the 2nd column and v1 is the first but the bars do not correspond to the numbers at all, they are all out of order and there is no discernible pattern.  How are these dates being interpreted and rearranged?

I tested it on some test data with same date format and its working fine

```
    V1          V2
    01/31/1996  1
    02/29/1996  5
    03/31/1996  3
    04/30/1996  12
    05/31/1996  2
    06/30/1996  -5
    07/31/1996  7
    08/31/1996  11
    09/30/1996  1
    10/31/1996  0
```

ok so following the comments and using str(differences), I get

'data.frame':   203 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ V1: Factor w/ 203 levels "01/31/1996","01/31/1997",..: 1 30 35 52 69 86 103 120 137 154 ...
 $ V2: num  -7.3667 0.9413 9.3252 0.3147 8.8593 ...
 $ V3: int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...

testing on more basic data,

```
01/31/1996      1
02/29/1996      2
03/31/1996      3
04/30/1996      4
05/31/1996      5
06/30/1996      6
07/31/1996      7
08/31/1996      8
09/30/1996      9
10/31/1996      10
..
on and on until 200.
```

the graph looks like

```
  |   |   |   |   | 
 ||  ||  ||  ||  ||
||| ||| ||| ||| |||
```

instead of

```
         |
        ||
       |||
      ||||
     |||||
    ||||||
   |||||||
```

graphs are not completely accurate but that's the idea.

so they are getting tiled somehow but I have no idea why, I just want to plot them one by one from left to right based on the date

Comment: Show us `str(differences)`. V2 is probably a factor.

Comment: Would be helpful if you could provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) to help the people responding to your question.

Answer (score 0):

I think that your date variable is being treated as a factor and ordered alphabetically instead of chronologically. You need to change it to date or at least order the factor by date.